# Wordpress addon to add data to a database and then call the data

Tags: database, wordpress

I know this question is probably going to get downvoted and I will probably get into trouble but I am hoping someone may be able to help me with my situation.

On my site I use json to download data from an external source, and then I style it beautifully.

Within the json data is an individual ID for each data set.

What I want to accomplish is to have a database where I can insert the ID and a url link.

I have created the table within the wordpress database via phpMyAdmin, but I want to create a page within the admin section where I can simply add the data in.

For displaying the json data I use a php insert addon, within that php clip i want to do a piece of code that checks the database for the id within my custom database and displays the link.

I will be honest I don't know where to start on this, even if its just a link to a source that shows me how to create an admin page and submit data to the database within wordpress dashboard.

I really appreciate any help given and like I say I know I should try harder, but when ever I do a search all I get is 100's of references to add an admin to the database manually.

Thanks,

Adam

Edit I just realized I never put any table information in my question.

The table name within wordpress is called: wp_home_tickets
within that are 3 fields: id (auto increasement), gameid (numeric) and ticketlink (text)

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding a custom settings page in your admin, use the Settings API https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

Here is a nice tutorial using it https://deliciousbrains.com/create-wordpress-plugin-settings-page/#wp-settings-api

To fetch data from your custom table, use the wpdb class https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/. More specifically, you can use wpdb::get_results if you will have multiple rows sharing the same id https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

Or wpdb::get_row if you will ever only have one https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thank you so much for your links, they helped a ton, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wishing to see how it was done, here is how I did it.

I created a file in my theme called db_admin_menu.php and added the following to it:

```
<?php
function ticket_admin_menu() {
 global $team_page;
 add_menu_page( __( 'Tickets', 'sports-bench' ), __( 'Tickets', 'sports-bench' ), 'edit_posts', 'add_data', 'ticket_page_handler', 'dashicons-groups', 6 ) ;
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ticket_admin_menu' );

function ticket_page_handler() {
   $table_name = 'wp_home_tickets';
   global $wpdb;
   echo '<form method="POST" action="?page=add_data">
       <label>Team ID: </label><input type="text" name="gameid" /><br />
       <label>Ticket Link: </label><input type="text" name="ticketlink" /><br />
       <input type="submit" value="submit" />
       </form>';

   $default = array(
     'gameid' => '',
     'ticketlink' => '',
   );
  $item = shortcode_atts( $default, $_REQUEST );
  $gameid = $item['gameid'];
  if ($wpdb->get_var("SELECT * FROM wp_home_tickets WHERE gameid = $gameid ")) { echo 'Ticket already exists for this game.'; goto skip; }
  if (!empty($_POST)) { $wpdb->insert( $table_name, $item ); }
  skip:
}
?>
```

I then put this code in my script that fetches and displays the json:

```
$matchid = $match['id'];
$ticket_url = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ticketlink FROM wp_home_tickets WHERE gameid = '$matchid' ");
if ($ticket_url) { echo '<a href="'.$ticket_url.'" class="gamedetail">Get Tickets</a>'; }
```

I hope someone does find it of use, i did have to use a wordpress plugin called `Insert PHP Code Snippet' by xyzscripts to be able to snippet the php to a shortcode, but that is not the purpose of this post.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi! I recommend to those db methods, you add wpdb::prepare https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/ for safe execution.